# Grunt Error, bower does nothing, Ubuntu precise 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, gruntjs, npm, bower

I have a machine on digital ocean build with puphpet (Ubuntu 12.04).
I use angular-generator of Yeoman
I work on windows, everything is fine & I just want to put my work on the ubuntu.
I put files on it and I do this :

```
$ bower install (do nothing)
$ npm install
    npm WARN package.json love@0.0.1 No description
    npm WARN package.json love@0.0.1 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json love@0.0.1 No README data
    npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/[***]/love/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/bower requires chalk@'0.5.0' but will load
    npm WARN unmet dependency /var/www/[***]/love/node_modules/grunt-google-cdn/node_modules/chalk,
    npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
$ grunt
    Loading "autoprefixer.js" tasks...ERROR
    >> Error: Cannot find module 'postcss'
    Loading "connect.js" tasks...ERROR
    >> Error: Cannot find module 'cookie-signature'
    Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...ERROR
    >> Error: Cannot find module 'async'

    Running "newer:jshint" (newer) task

    Running "newer:jshint:all" (newer) task

    Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task

    app/scripts/controllers/timer.js
      line 110  col 29  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 113  col 30  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 116  col 31  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
      line 11   col 68  '$log' is defined but never used.
      line 11   col 57  '$location' is defined but never used.

    ✖ 5 problems

    Warning: Task "jshint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.


    Execution Time (2015-01-27 11:44:14 UTC)
    loading tasks      15ms  ▇▇▇ 3%
    newer:jshint        7ms  ▇▇ 1%
    newer:jshint:all   20ms  ▇▇▇ 4%
    jshint:all        467ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 92%
    Total 510ms
```

Comment: I encountered a very similar problem with the same first two lines of the error message (">> Error: Cannot find module 'postcss'"). After installing all of the modules not found via "npm install <package>" I was able to get it running. Maybe you can give it a try ...